# tar: Unexpected EOF in archive

Tags: shell, command, centos, extract, tar

I am trying extract .tar.gz file it but with no luck

```
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

the file tar.gz include another file.tar only which is has the issue

when i trying to extract .tar file i got

```
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

i tried –ignore-zeros –ignore-failed-read with no luck

how could i extract this file even if it corrupted ?

Comment: Please show the `tar` command you are using, are you using `-z`?  Also, use `file` to check the file type.

Comment: the file type tar.gz: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Fri Nov  2 11:42:56 2012

Answer (score 1):

You tar file is truncated. `tar` extracts everything present in the archive but cannot invent the missing part.

Comment: i want to extract everything and skip the missing part , how could i do it ?

Comment: The missing part is at the end, you can't but skip the missing part.